# Clapp oscillator PCB not working when ground pin is connected

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, oscillator

I have designed a Clapp oscillator working at 25MHz. The catch is I designed the circuit to be a part of frequency compensation network. So, I incorporated a few reverse-biased varactors whose capacitance can be varied simply by a separate DC tuning input. The first figure is the schematic of the circuit. The second figure is the PCB of the oscillator. Red wire is the DC supply input, black is the ground, and blue is the DC tuning input to the varactors.

When I connect the ground (black) wire to the actual ground (neutral) of the supply, I read nothing from the oscilloscope. However, when I leave the ground wire open and make the ground connections through the blue wire, I see a very decent 25MHz sine wave. Note that (-) of the DC supply is always connected to the neutral.

One thing apparent to me is, even though I do not connect the black wire and leave it open, it is actually connected to the ground through the oscilloscope. There is a ground plane underneath and vias connect ground traces together.

Why do you think this might be the case? LTSpice simulation works just fine by the way. Transient analysis as well as a S parameter analysis show oscillations at the required frequency. Also, I replaced all the varactors with a simple 39pF cap but changed nothing. Circuit only works when the apparent ground is not connected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the PCB artwork as well, it's hard to see what the parasitics are on the bottom of the board.

Comment: The layout seems not the same as your schematic. I see at least 2 differences: the diode connection to CV, and the components between the 50 ohm output and GND. There may be more, but it's hard to tell without identifying the components. Also, are the values in the sim real? 0.0008pF? 8 *femto* farad?

Comment: So this does work when the emitter has a 50 ohm load?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I added the pcb layout as you desired.

Comment: @hacktastical, yes, you see it right. It is a crystal model and the xtal vendor and many many other sources on the internet suggests to use similar values for the series capacitance of the crystal. The parallel RLC structure to the crystal is the modelling of the 3rd overtone mode, i.e. 75MHZ mode. There are some guidelines on the internet on how to model crystals properly and I followed them.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, yes, it works just fine, as long as the black wire is left open in the air.